# joomla k2 - Allowed memory size of 5242880 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, apache, joomla, wamp, joomla-k2

I have an issue about memory limit locally (on `windows`), when trying to save a `k2` item in `joomla`. At first, the error is related to `k2 extrafield`, but when I deactivate the concerned function, the same error appear with `joomla plugins` (`pagebreak plugin`).

I have added `memory_limit` rule in `php.ini`, `htaccess` and through `ini_set() php function`, but the message error doesnt disappear. I have even added an `.htaccess` inside the folder containing the file that's causing the error.

The error message shown is:
`Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 5242880 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 98304 bytes) in ..\\web\\administrator\\components\\com_k2\\lib\\JSON.php on line 331`

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you restart Apache after making changes to the *php.ini*?

Comment: Restarted the apache?

Comment: Of course I restarted it & joomla `information tab` shows the changed memory_limit.

Comment: to what value did you set it?

Comment: to `memory_limit = 1024M`

Comment: Try setting it to something higher. On my local host, I have mine set to `memory_limit = 128M`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm suspecting some `ini_set` found in k2 components files that I have to remove.
The correct solution is to edit the last field in `k2 parameters` in `joomla adminstration`(for image memory limit), and increment it from `5M` to something as `100M` (100 Mo).

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure K2 developers would **not** start overriding php.ini settings in their extension

Comment: You're pretty wrong I've found a lot of `ini_set` inside `k2 models`.

Comment: I have to agree with @h4k1m. Joomla plugin developers almost always try and make their plugins work by disregarding the entire possible structure of a tailored application. They tend to go for "the quick fix" approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP configuration at the server has a memory limit of **8 Mb**, which is rather low.
I'd recommend to set it to **32 Mb**.

Try to set `ini_mem('memory_limit','12M');`